# How can I get just the filename to delete a file in AWS?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

I am deleting a file from AWS like this:

```
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3',
    aws_access_key_id = 'BLABLABLABLA',
    aws_secret_access_key = 'bLABla+2+bLbLABlaABla')

    bucket_name = 'mydoc'
    file_name = 'some_path/12bw.png'
    s3.Object(bucket_name, file_name).delete()
```

To delete the record and AWS file I created in views.py:

```
def slett(request, id):
    dokument = Dokument.objects.get(id=id)
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3',
    aws_access_key_id = 'BLABLABLABLA',
    aws_secret_access_key = 'bLABla+2+bLbLABlaABla')


    bucket_name = 'mydoc'
    file_name = dokument.file.url
    
    s3.Object(bucket_name, file_name).delete()
    dokument.delete()
    return HttpResponse(file_name)
```

But this is not working. I'm getting the complete URL for the file. What I need is the path from bucket. Like:

`file_name = 'some_path/bw.png'`

Comment: If you're referring to standard S3 URLs described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-bucket-intro.html) then parse the key from the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you!

This is what I did:

```
file_name = dokument.file.url
filepath = urlparse(file_name).path
```